# display row where id is not displayed

Tags: mysql, sql

Using one table, I am trying to run a query that matches a userid to a course. 
The goal is to see the courses that the userid is not in, 
So far I can display the usid's that are not in all the courses, but now I want to display the courses that they are not in

```
SELECT usid, course, COUNT(*)
FROM COURSE_COMMENTS
WHERE course in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
GROUP BY usid
HAVING COUNT(*) < 8
```

Also, neither usid, nor course are primary so they can show up multiple times.
any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the schema

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `courses` table, you can do something like this:

```
select u.usid, c.course
from (select distinct course from courses where course in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) c cross join
     (select distinct usid from course_comments) u left join
     course_comments cc
     on cc.course = c.course and cc.usid = u.usid
where cc.course is null;
```

Comment: Thats the rough part, they are in the same table. The actual table schemais much more confusing than what I have typed, but it is the general idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: @amazingacademy . . . You can actually make the first subquery `select distinct course from course_comments . . .)`.  However, I was concerned that not all courses would necessarily be in that table.

Comment: I see where you are headed with this, but now i am getting 'usid in field list is ambiguous'. Also, i created a courses table that just lists all of my courses.